# Make selenium webdriver window appear on the foreground

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How can I make the Chrome window selenium webdriver opens appear on the foreground? Basically, I want to do the opposit of "headless".

`nav = webdriver.Chrome()`

I would like this to generate a window on the foreground.

Comment: Normally it opens the chrome browser window in the foreground only, what is happening in your case?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the required methods, classes from selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

and then create a drive object

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') #provide the chrome driver location
```

After running this line of code, a chrome window will open.